# Multiple nested axios calls with return values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using Vue and making multiple calls with `axios` and I am just curious if there is a different approach for this. My code is working but I don't like the way it is structured and I would love to get some input on that.

**I feel like this is so messy and probably there should be a better way to do this:**

```
login: function() {
    this.toggleLoading();

    this.findUser().then(success => {
        if(success) {
            this.validateSomething().then(success => {
                if(success) {
                    this.auth();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

`findUser` and `validateSomething` are structured like this:

```
findUser: function() {
    return axios
    .post('/find-user', {
        id: this.id
    })
    .then(response => {
        if(response.data.success) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.addErrors(response.data.message);
            this.toggleLoading();
            return false;
        }
    })
    .catch(this.catchAll)
},
```

I dont wanna merge the `findUser` and `validateSomething` functions because I want to be able to use them separately.

**But basically, I am trying to achive something like this instead:**

```
login: function() {

    this.toggleLoading();

    if(!this.findUser()) {
        return false;
    }

    if(this.validateSomething()) {
        this.auth();
    }
}
```

What would be the best practice for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @canbax mentioning, use `async` method with the keyword await. See the small example below. The code will wait to proceed to the next line on each `await` until the promise is ready.

```
login: async function() {
    this.toggleLoading();

    const bool = await this.findUser();

    const validated = await this.validateSomething();

    return this.auth();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! (Just a small typo in the code you provided, maybe you can edit it :)
async login: function() {
should be
login: async function() {

Answer (score 2):

you can use async/await, but if you're ok with promises you can just clean it up

instead of nesting the promisses like this:

```js
login: function() {
    this.toggleLoading();

    this.findUser().then(success => {
        if(success) {
            this.validateSomething().then(success => {
                if(success) {
                    this.auth();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

you can chain them, like this :

```js
login: function() {
  this.toggleLoading();

  this.findUser()
    .then(success => {
      if (success) {
        // returning a promise will allow you to chain the next then below
        return this.validateSomething();
      }
      // if success is not truthy, throw error, which will be caught by catch at end and skip other promise execution
      throw new Error('unsuccessful login')
    })
    .then(success => {
      if (success) {
        return this.auth();
      }
      throw new Error('some other reason that it failed')
    })
    .then(success=>{
      return success
    })
    .catch(err=> handle(err)) // then handle the error

}
```

### TL;DR;

Promises (without async/await) are just fine, the problem is you're implementing them like they are callbacks, instead of using the `.then` the intended way, which can be easily resolved.

Comment: I decided to do it with async, but thank you for this input.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) functions which are introduced in ES2017. You can **wait** result of an `async` function with keyword `await`. Please check the docs.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.